# How to query for work items for current team in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I am getting started with TFS 2015 and I need to know how to make a query that returns all of the work items for the current iteration for the current team. I have Iteration Path Under @CurrentIteration and Work Item Type = User Story, but I can find a macro similar to @CurrentIteration that would get the current team or team area. How do I filter out the stories for all other teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not able to do this through a query.  You could check the [Query macros or variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/query-operators-variables#query-macros-or-variables),  use the macros described in the following table to filter your queries based on specific fields. There is not any team area related macro.

[image]

Besides, actually as far as I know work items can only be assigned to specific people not groups. However, **for a workaround**. By assigning a work item to a specific **area path** you basically **assign it to a team**.  If you use the area path for something else today, you can also use another string field in the work item that specifies the team.
 (https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/scale/portfolio-management)

So you could use **Area Path** to do the filter.

Answer (score 0):

This won't directly solve your problem but you can use 'Assigned to' 'In Group' and then use a user group e.g. '[Home]\Team NI'.  This will return tickets assigned to the group or group members but assumes the tickets are assigned appropriately (rather than being unassigned).   YMMV but I've found it useful at times to get around this limitation.   TFS Azure 2019 now also includes @TeamAreas - which is helpful unless you have multiple teams using the same areas.